# Kali Linux not loading from USB

Tags: system-installation, kali-linux, live-usb

I had a working copy of Kali Linux on a USB and something happened and I accidentally formatted the USB. I have placed the 64 bit iso back on the USB with LinuxLive USB, and changed my boot settings to boot from USB. Now when it loads up all I get is a flashing `_` and nothing ever happens. Any ideas what to do ?

Comment: Try using a different tool to create the USB.

Comment: Such as Win32? Any idea what is causing the LinuxLive USB to not work anymore? I checked the USB and there are files on it, not sure if all of them, but there are files on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some distributions don't work well with certain live USB creation tools. Your best bet is to just create the USB again using a different tool. For example:

- [Live USB multiboot](http://liveusb.info/dotclear/)
- [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)
- [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)

A great source of information for this kind of thing is the [pendrive linux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com) website.